# First DOS videogame ever?

Tags: gaming-history, dos

I wanna know the first videogame ever released for DOS (any version of it). When I was a kid I was a heavy user of DOS, and I remember playing lots of very old games which were developed way before I was even born. The oldest game I remember playing is [Paratrooper](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paratrooper_%28video_game%29), which was released in 1982. That's pretty old for the DOS platform, considering it got popular in 1981.

Any help?

Comment: Related meta discussion: http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/2165/are-what-was-the-first-questions-on-topic

Comment: Why closed? I've just read that post and I still don't understand where to ask this!

Comment: *MAYBE* [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128548/what-stack-overflow-is-not) will help you understand a little more how SE works.

Answer (score 2):

One possible contender - [DONKEY.BAS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DONKEY.BAS), one of the sample programs written in BASIC that shipped with IBM PC DOS v1.0 in August 1981 (according to [this timeline](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timeline_of_x86_DOS_operating_systems)).

Wikipedia also has a list of [MS-DOS games](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Index_of_MS-DOS_games) (which to my eye looks pretty non-exhaustive), which has [entries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-1_Nuclear_Bomber) [from](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defender_%28video_game%29) [1980](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rescue_at_Rigel) and even one from [1979](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dunjonquest_%28series%29). Since these games were released on multiple platforms and DOS was not commercially available until 1981, it seems likely that the dates shown were for their initial release on *any* platform. The actual DOS port and release may have happened some years later.

I suspect this may be a tricky question to answer - after all, [we can't even prove when Super Mario Bros was released](http://www.gamasutra.com/view/feature/167392/sad_but_true_we_cant_prove_when_.php?print=1).

Comment: Oh, yeah! I remember playing that game too! So that should be the oldest one. Anyway, I'm more interested in independent games, but your info is great. Thanks!